# Bind Fragment/Activity to MVP View contract with Dagger Hilt

Tags: dagger-hilt

I am currently trying to migrate from dagger-android to Hilt. Previously I used @Bind to bind instances of fragments and activities to the corresponding MVP View contract. Is there a way to do the same with Hilt? It doesn't seem to be able to inject sepcific fragments and activities?

Comment: Can you give an example code snippet you're trying to replace?

Answer (score 0):

We need some code to give a proper answer, but I think you need something like

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class MyScreenModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindMyScreenFragment(impl: ScreenFragment): MyScreenContract.View


    @ActivityScoped
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindMyScreenPresenter(impl: ScreenPresenter): MyScreenContract.Presenter

}
```

Don't forget:

- Add '@Inject' to the Fragment and Presenter constructors
- Add @AndroidEntryPoint to MyScreenActivity and MyScreenFragment

**NOTE:** Consider if the Presenter should be bounded to the Fragment lifecycle. In this case, the presenter binding should have it's own module marked with *@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)* and the binding scoped to @FragmentScoped

Comment: I also have the same question and I added the full code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306914/how-to-mvp-in-dagger-hilt.  Adding @ActivityScoped didn't work.