# How to MVP in Dagger Hilt?

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

I can't compile the code using a Model View Presenter(MVP) Hilt approach.

I get this error:
*/MotionPoC/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/aria/motionpoc/di/MotionApp_HiltComponents.java:145: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.aria.motionpoc.coupon.MainActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.*

The code itself:

***MainActivity.kt***

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainContract.View {

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: MainContract.Presenter
```

***MainPresenter.kt***

```
class MainPresenter @Inject constructor(
    private val view: MainContract.View
): MainContract.Presenter {

    override fun onViewCreated() {
        view.showList()
    }
}
```

***MainModule.kt***

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class MainModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindActivity(view: MainActivity): MainContract.View

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindPresenter(impl: MainPresenter): MainContract.Presenter
}
```

***MotionApp.kt***

```
@HiltAndroidApp
open class MotionApp : Application()
```

**Solved! Thank you for the help Manuel Vivo!**
https://github.com/riodext/AndroidDaggerHiltMVP

Comment: You are missing @AndroidEntryPoint on your MainActivity and you have a Circle dependency which won't compile. The activity needs a presenter and the presenter needs the activity to initialise

Comment: I already had the @AndroidEntryPoint (I forgot to put it here). And about the Cicle dependency, how would you implement the MVP? Thanks for answering!

Comment: I mean, how can I call methods from the View in my Presenter? Keeping both Activity and Presenter decoupled from each other.

Comment: I would set the View in the presenter on the onCreate, and in onDestroy I would set it to null.
Something like 
override onCreate(blabla) {
    super.onCreate(blala)
    presenter.setView(this)
}

Comment: I wanted to do the injection via constructor, and not manually. Solved in: https://github.com/riodext/AndroidDaggerHiltMVP

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're depending on a specific implementation of Activity and that dependency (i.e. `MainActivity`) is not satisfied in the code.

You'll have to provide that as a binding in the same module:

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
object MainActivityModule {

    @Provides
    fun bindActivity(activity: Activity): MainActivity {
        return activity as MainActivity
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried this but I got this error in the bindActivity: /di/MainModule.java:21: error: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type

Comment: Is that because your Activity is of other type? Try AppCompatActivity

Comment: I uploaded the project in: https://github.com/riodext/AndroidDaggerHiltMVP

Comment: Solved! If anyone want to see the solution is in the link above

Comment: Worked well! Thank you.